# Swift: EGODataBaseRowResult does not have a member named Generator

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I am getting the error EGODatabaseResult does not have a member named Generator on this line `for row : EGODatabaseRow in result { }`. I am not sure what this means and every answer on stackoverflow seems to not relate to my problem. Any suggestions or tips are appreciated. Here is the full swift code.

```
var result : EGODatabaseResult = self.mEGODataBase!.executeQuery(query)

for row : EGODatabaseRow in result { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you will look at [EGODatabaseResult.h](https://github.com/enormego/egodatabase/blob/master/Classes/EGODatabaseResult.h), then you will see that it implements only `NSFastEnumeration` protocol (if you not familiar with protocols in programming languages, then in this case some of them enable to use `for el: T in obj` and other literals). If you want to do such construction, then this class must implement `Generator` protocol (this doesn't).

But there are one solution (to use literal for array, not just class itself):

```
var result: EGODatabaseResult = self.mEGODataBase!.executeQuery(query)
for row: EGODatabaseRow in result.rows as [EGODatabaseRow] { }
```